# Lenovo Ubuntu partition problem

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu for the first time on my Lenovo laptop and I keep getting this:

> If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks. Otherwise you will be able to make further changes manually.
>   **WARNING: This will destroy all data on any parttions you have removed as well as on the partitions that are going to be formatted.**

```
The partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda)

The following partitions are going to be formatted:
partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4 
partition #5 of SCSI1 (0,0,0 (sda) sd swap
```

Comment: Is it dual boot or fresh install?

Comment: If fresh install backup your data and proceed,no problem @Joseph

Comment: Please clarify the current state of your system what you want to achieve, i. e. how you want the system to be partitioned after the Ubuntu installation. Are there any other operating systems or previous partitions with valuable data involved?

Comment: I would split partition 1 to have a root `/` and a home `/home`  partition. It is useful when you update between versions; you can do a clean install without having to move your home files.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong. It's a normal message that shows to 'warn' you  that after this step your disk will be used entirely for the Ubuntu installation. This message appears every time an Ubuntu installation is done.